# Getting Atomic Errors With Lists

Tags: r

I'm implementing an A-star algorithm in R and keep getting the "Error during wrapup: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" when trying to use the sapply function.

This is my structure:

```
frontier <- list()
starting_node = list(1, 1)
frontier <- append(frontier, list(node = starting_node, cost = 0, path = list()))
costs = sapply(frontier,function(item)item$cost)
```

This returns error. Does anyone have any idea what's causing this issue? I feel as though I'm using lists, for which the $ operation should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

The cost element of your list frontier is actually of the atomic type numeric for which the $ operator is not defined:

```r
library(tidyverse)
frontier <- list()
starting_node = list(1, 1)
frontier <- append(frontier, list(node = starting_node, cost = 0, path = list()))
frontier %>% sapply(class)
#>      node      cost      path 
#>    "list" "numeric"    "list"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`sapply` applies the function using $ to every element so every element must be a list itself.

Comment: Is there any simple way of working around this?

Comment: Do you just wanna do `frontier$cost` ? Why use `sapply`?

Comment: I need to return costs as a list, as I'm looking to use the which.min(costs) function on it to find at what index the lowest cost is in the list frontier.

Comment: How about frontiers <- list(costs = list(0))?